# How can I terminate a program when the user input is not a valid password

Tags: java, passwords

I'm new in java programming, How can I terminate my program when the user input is not a valid password?

Here is my code that has a problem

```
final int MAX = 8;
    final int MIN_Uppercase = 1;
    final int NUM_Digits = 1;
    final int Special = 1;
    
    int invalidCount = 0;
    int uppercaseCounter = 0;
    int digitCounter = 0;
    int specialCounter = 0;
    int spaceCounter = 0;
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    System.out.println ("Enter Name: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    int spacePosition = name.indexOf(" ");
    
    System.out.print ("\n");
    
    System.out.println ("Enter Birthday (MM DD YYYY): ");
    String birthday = sc.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print ("\n");
    
    System.out.println ("Enter password: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    String password = input.nextLine();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i ++)
        {
          char c = password.charAt(i);
          
          if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
            uppercaseCounter ++;
          
          if (c == ' ')
            spaceCounter ++;
          
          if (c == '$' || c == '#' || c == '?' || c == '!' || c == '_' || c == '=' || c == '%' || c == '.')
            specialCounter ++;
          
          else if (Character.isDigit(c))
            digitCounter ++;
        }
    if (password.length() >= MAX && uppercaseCounter >= MIN_Uppercase && specialCounter == 1 && digitCounter == 1)
    {
      System.out.println(" ");
      
      System.out.println ("\n");
    }
    else
    {
      
      if (password.length() < MAX)
        System.out.println("Enter atleast 8 characters");
      
      if (spaceCounter > 0)
        System.out.println("Password contains whitespaces");
      
      if (uppercaseCounter < MIN_Uppercase)
        System.out.println("Enter atleast 1 Uppercase Character");
      
      if (digitCounter < 1)
        System.out.println("Enter atleast 1 digit");
      
      if (specialCounter < 1)
        System.out.println("Enter atleast 1 special character");
      
      System.out.print ("\n");
      
      
    }
    
    System.out.println ("Your login details");
    System.out.print ("\n");
    
    System.out.println ("Name    : " + name);
    System.out.println ("Birthday: " + birthday);
    System.out.println ("Username: " + name.substring(0, 2) + name.substring(spacePosition + 3) + birthday.substring(3,5));
    System.out.println ("Password: " + password);
```

The problem is that when the user enters an invalid password, the process will continue to print the login details.

I want to know how I can terminate the program or loop back into entering the password.

If the password is valid, then the details will print; if the password is invalid, then the program will loop back to requesting the password or the program will be terminated.

Comment: Note that this is a fine way to make your users make __insecure__ passwords, and inconvenience them while you're at it, and you have more code to maintain. Lose-Lose-Lose. [more info](https://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having WHILE loop to contain the part of your code where the user types in a password. You can use a variable to keep track if the password is valid or keep track of the number of times the user goes through the loop and break out of it under certain conditions.

```
PSEUDO CODE:
int ntimes = 0;
boolean isValid = false;
while(isValid == false){
  //Prompt for Password
  //User Enters Password
  if(password is valid){
    isValid = true;
  }
  else{
   ntimes++;
  }
  if(ntimes == 7) break;
}

if(isValid == false){
  "You entered a bad password too many times."
  QUIT
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm new at java programming, how can I enter the code? thankyou

Comment: Since you have to enter the loop at least once before you can validate the state, a `do-while` loop would be a more suitable construct ... poor `do-while` is always overlooked  - IMHO

Comment: @Amimir Maybe start with [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)